# Why converting Double to Int doesn't return optional Int in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, int

Converting a String to Int returns an optional value but converting a Double to Int does not return an optional value. Why is that? I wanted to check if a double value is bigger than maximum Int value, but because converting function does not return an optional value, I am not be able to check by using optional binding.

```
var stringNumber: String = "555"
var intValue = Int(stringNumber) // returns optional(555)

var doubleNumber: Double = 555
var fromDoubleToInt = Int(doubleNumber) // returns 555
```

So if I try to convert a double number bigger than maximum Integer, it crashes instead of returning nil.

```
var doubleNumber: Double = 55555555555555555555
var fromDoubleToInt = Int(doubleNumber) // Crashes here
```

I know that there's another way to check if a double number is bigger than maximum Integer value, but I'm curious as why it's happening this way.

Comment: I'd guess that it's because there's no doubt that there's an integral version of the Double, and it would be very inconvenient to always be unwrapping in addition to all the other hoops that Swift numerics make you jump through. Overflow conditions in Swift _do_ crash in general, so it's not all that surprising that this one does too. If you don't like it, you can certainly write a function that _does_ return an Optional!

Answer (score 5):

If we consider that for *most* doubles, a conversion to `Int` simply means dropping the decimal part:

```
let pieInt = Int(3.14159) // 3
```

Then the only case in which the `Int(Double)` constructor returns `nil` is in the case of an overflow.

With strings, converting to `Int` returns an optional, because generally, strings, such as "Hello world!" cannot be represented as an `Int` in a way that universally makes sense.  So we return `nil` in the case that the string cannot be represented as an integer.  This includes, by the way, values that can be perfectly represented as doubles or floats:

Consider:

```
let iPi = Int("3.14159")
let dPi = Double("3.14159")
```

In this case, `iPi` is `nil` while `dPi` is `3.14159`.  Why?  Because `"3.14159"` doesn't have a valid `Int` representation.

But meanwhile, when we use the `Int` constructor which takes a `Double` and returns non-optional, we get a value.

So, if that constructor is changed to return an optional, why would it return `3` for `3.14159` instead of `nil`?  `3.14159` can't be represented as an integer.

But if you want a method that returns an optional `Int`, returning `nil` when the `Double` would overflow, you can just write that method.

```
extension Double {
    func toInt() -> Int? {
        let minInt = Double(Int.min)
        let maxInt = Double(Int.max)

        guard case minInt ... maxInt = self else {
            return nil
        }

        return Int(self)
    }
}

let a = 3.14159.toInt() // returns 3
let b = 555555555555555555555.5.toInt() // returns nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Failable initializers and methods with Optional return types are designed for scenarios where you, the programmer, can't know whether a parameter value will cause failure, or where verifying that an operation will succeed is equivalent to performing the operation:

```
let intFromString = Int(someString)
let valueFromDict = dict[someKey]
```

Parsing an integer from a string requires checking the string for numeric/non-numeric characters, so the check is the same as the work. Likewise, checking a dictionary for the existence of a key is the same as looking up the value for the key.

By contrast, certain operations are things where you, the programmer, need to verify upfront that your parameters or preconditions meet expectations:

```
let foo = someArray[index]
let bar = UInt32(someUInt64)
let baz: UInt = someUInt - anotherUInt
```

You can — and in most cases should — test at runtime whether `index < someArray.count` and `someUInt64 < UInt32.max` and `someUInt > anotherUInt`. These assumptions are fundamental to working with those kinds of types. On the one hand, you [really want to design around them from the start](https://ima.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/ariane.html). On the other, you don't want every bit of math you do to be peppered with Optional unwrapping — that's why we have types whose axioms are stated upfront.